# How to remove "Add to Windows Media Player list" from context menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry, windows-media-player, context-menu

When Windows Media Player is the default player in Windows, the right-click context menu for certain music files includes an item called `"Add to Windows Media Player list"`. This is par-for-the-course with WMP, which includes tons of these context menu items. However, [unlike other context menu items](https://superuser.com/a/235385/323079), which are usually relatively easy to get rid of because they  require the deletion of a handful of sub-keys in the same usual places, this particular item is a lot trickier to find, and I couldn't find anything on doing so via Google or this site.

[image]

**So, how do you get rid of the "Add to Windows Media Player list" context menu item?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent a good few hours yesterday searching through the registry, removing the item on my own machine and then writing scripts to automate the process of removing (and restoring) the problem context menu item. Note that I only tested on my Windows 7 machine running Windows Media Player 12, and even though I automate this process as much as I possibly can, there is always the risk that things can go wrong.

*Therefore, before undertaking this tweak, create a Restore Point from which you can go back to in case anything does go wrong. If you run the scripts provided below and they don't do anything, simply restore your computer to that restore point to ensure you're in no worse a position than you were when you started.*

## **Removing the "Add to Windows Media Player list" context menu item**

[image]

It turns out the corresponding registry keys are hard to find because they're not in any of the usual places where, typically, a single registry key corresponds to all folders, or files of a specific type. Instead, there's a separate key for each extension that the context menu item appears on. These keys are located in registry paths with the following format:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.3G2\shell\Enqueue`

...where `.3G2` is the extension that the context menu item applies to, and `Enqueue` is the key that needs to be deleted to remove the menu item for all `.3G2` files. There are **23 different extensions** that these files need to be deleted for.

Also note that the key says WMP11 even though I'm running version 12 - this could mean that all versions of Windows Media Player are referred to as `WMP11` in the Registry, and that, therefore, the scripts below will work for both previous and later versions of Windows 7. Either way, there's no harm in trying so long as you have a recent restore point to hand.

### To remove the context menu items for each extension

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.3G2\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.3GP\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.ADTS\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.AIFF\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.ASF\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.ASX\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.AU\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.AVI\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.M2TS\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.m3u\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.M4A\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MIDI\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MOV\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MP3\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MP4\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MPEG\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.TTS\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WAV\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WAX\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.wma\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WMV\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WPL\shell\Enqueue]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WVX\shell\Enqueue]
```

The above script will delete all the listed `Enqueue` keys, removing the `Add to Windows Media Player list` context menu item from all the file extensions it appears in. Copy-and-paste the script into a plain text file and give it the `.reg` extension. Then run the file and click Yes in the prompt that appears. To test, right-click on any music file. Et voila!

[image]

### To restore the context menu items for each extension

So you've finally removed the `Add to Windows Media Player list` context menu item, only to decide that you've grown quite fond of it and want it back after all. No problem. Restoring the context menu item is a little more complicated than removing it, but it can still be done.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.3G2\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.3G2\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.3GP\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.3GP\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.ADTS\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.ADTS\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.AIFF\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.AIFF\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.ASF\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.ASF\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.ASX\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.ASX\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.AU\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.AU\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.AVI\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.AVI\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.M2TS\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.M2TS\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.m3u\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.m3u\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.M4A\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.M4A\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MIDI\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MIDI\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MOV\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MOV\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MP3\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MP3\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MP4\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MP4\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MPEG\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MPEG\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.TTS\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.TTS\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WAV\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WAV\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WAX\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WAX\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.wma\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.wma\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WMV\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WMV\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WPL\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WPL\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WVX\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WVX\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"
```

Once again, place the script in a `.reg` file, run it, and test.

I'd also appreciate people letting me know if any of these solutions worked for them on older or newer versions of Windows Media Player and/or Windows itself.

Comment: It does not appear to work on Windows 10 :/

Comment: Not sure how/whether this solution differs from the long .reg file offered by Winaero (https://winaero.com/blog/remove-windows-media-player-context-menu/).

Comment: this did not work either, for me (Win10 Home V21H2)

Answer (score 7):

I am using Windows 10 preview insiders build. I have essentially taken away all media player entries from the context menu.

1. Open control panel.
2. Click program and features.
3. Turn windows features on and off.
4. scroll down to >Media Features> open that tab up.
5. You will see a check box. **Uncheck only the 'Media Player' check box**.
6. **Click OK!**

Done.
Enjoy.

These steps remove media player from your computer. Users are encouraged to try Groove Music.

Comment: This does not appear on the menu (Step 5) now, using Win10 Home v21H2

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found (Win10 Home V21H2) -

**Solution Found:**

- [Remove Add to Windows Media Player list Context Menu in Windows 10 | Tutorials](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/83163-remove-add-windows-media-player-list-context-menu-windows-10-a.html)

This worked immediately without reboot. It performs the same as [Hashim Aziz's](https://superuser.com/users/323079/hashim-aziz) example, with the following -

**Working:**

```
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MediaCenter.WTVFile\shell\Enqueue]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Stack.Audio\shell\Enqueue]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Stack.Image\shell\Enqueue]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\audio\shell\Enqueue]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Directory.Audio\shell\Enqueue]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Directory.Image\shell\Enqueue]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP.DVR-MSFile\shell\Enqueue]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP.WTVFile\shell\Enqueue]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.<extension>\shell\Enqueue] .. a bunch here! 23 for me
```

Courtesy Shawn Brink, thank you for posting this!