# remove Add to Windows Media Player List from folders

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, windows-media-player, user-folders

I ran the script below, given in another post [How to remove "Add to Windows Media Player list" from context menu](https://superuser.com/questions/1143481/how-to-remove-add-to-windows-media-player-list-from-context-menu?noredirect=1&lq=1), and while it seems to have worked for individual files of the listed file-types, it still appears when right-clicking over a folder, containing, for example WAV or FLAC files, though not for mp3 files.

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.3G2\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.3GP\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.ADTS\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.AIFF\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.ASF\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.ASX\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.AU\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.AVI\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.M2TS\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.m3u\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.M4A\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MIDI\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MOV\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MP3\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MP4\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.MPEG\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.TTS\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WAV\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WAX\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.wma\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WMV\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WPL\shell\Enqueue]
> [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.WVX\shell\Enqueue]

How can I get rid of it for all folders as well?

The topic began on [How to remove "Add to Windows Media Player list" from context menu](https://superuser.com/questions/1143481/how-to-remove-add-to-windows-media-player-list-from-context-menu/1277845?noredirect=1#comment1886613_1277845)

but it didn't address the issue of context menu when right-clicking on folders.

Comment: OK. Comments deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The following .reg file will remove the context menu item from folders:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Directory.Audio\shell\Enqueue]
```

Just in case you want to get the context menu item back again, here's the .reg file to do that:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Directory.Audio\shell\Enqueue]
@="&Add to Windows Media Player list"
"MUIVerb"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
  6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
  00,75,00,6e,00,72,00,65,00,67,00,6d,00,70,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,\
  2c,00,2d,00,39,00,38,00,30,00,30,00,00,00
"NeverDefault"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\Directory.Audio\shell\Enqueue\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{45597c98-80f6-4549-84ff-752cf55e2d29}"
```